# Meteor mongo dates "invalid date" prototype?

Tags: javascript, meteor

noticed something a bit strange when querying in the console, that the dates I'm saving in mongo say they are of the type invalid date.

[image: screen shot from console]

I'm using collection 2 and define the schema for mongo like this :

```
createdAt: {
  type: Date,
  autoValue: function() {
    if (this.isInsert) {
      return new Date();
    } else if (this.isUpsert) {
      return { $setOnInsert: new Date() };
    } else {
      this.unset();
    }
  }
},
```

Why would it be invalid?  should it be invalid?

Comment: it's fine it's just the console output I know for a fact it's valid and all is good. Maybe the minimongo doesn't output it right to the console or the console. Nothing to worry about I just don't know the exact cause :)

Comment: thanks mark , that reassuring- I would like to understand why though.